# How to automatically power off the computer by calling the Win32 API function in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to schedule a shutdown of my computer on C# by calling the following API function but when I call this function nothing happens. Can anyone help me fix it.

```cs
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern UInt32 InitiateShutdownA(string lpMachineName, string lpMessage, UInt32 dwGracePeriod, UInt32 dwShutdownFlags, UInt32 dwReason);

internal const int EWX_POWEROFF = 0x00000008;
```

```cs
InitiateShutdownA(System.Environment.MachineName, "SHUTDOWN", 10, EWX_POWEROFF, 0);
```

Comment: What is the [return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiateshutdowna#return-value)?

Comment: Try [ExitWindowsEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-exitwindowsex) (you're already using `EWX_POWEROFF`, which is a `dwReason` of `ExitWindowsEx` - event though it's the same value) or [InitiateSystemShutdownExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-initiatesystemshutdownexw) (depending on the impersonation)

Comment: I found out why it didn't work because I didn't put my computer name variable in the first value of the function. Now it works!